# How do I make a grid with rounded corners?

Tags: objects

How do I make an object which is a grid with rounded corners as seen in the photo below?

The rounded corners are big and cut through multiple of the squares inside the grid.

[image: drawing of grid with rounded corners]

I tried by creating a plane then adding the `subdivision modifier`, then adding the `wireframe modifier`, but when I went to round the corners with  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>  it messed up the wires.

I then tried by converting it to a mesh, but that only allowed me to round corners on one square within the grid.

Comment: I'm not by my pc so I can't try it, but have you tried creating the outline you want, then using grid fill? I'm not sure if the corners will come out right, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a plane, round its corners with a bevel, create a second plane (same size), subdivide it, delete its faces, switch to top view, select the grid, shift select the first plane, go into *Edit* mode, then *Mesh > Knife Project* and it will cut the grid on the plane. Give some corrections:

[image]